# I want to make a redirection webform2 that shows a message based on the gender chosen in radiobutton in webform1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webforms, textbox

This is the `webform1` code and I made a string called pass to store the text in. What should I do in `webform2` to display the message based on the conditions?

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Response.Redirect("two.aspx", true);
    if (Request.Form["TextBox1"] != null && Request.Form["TextBox2"] != null) 
    {
        if (RadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            //pass = Response.ToString().Insert(Response.ToString().Count(), " " + "Welcome, " + Server.HtmlEncode(Request.QueryString["TextBox1"]) + ". <br/> The url is " + Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Url.ToString()));
            pass = "Thank you Ms. " + TextBox1.Text + "Your Registration has been successfully completed" ;
        }
        else if (RadioButton1.Checked)
        {
            pass = "Thank you Mr. " + TextBox1.Text + "Your Registration has been successfully completed";
        }                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Based on whatever i understand, i am providing some solution:

in webform1.aspx:->place below code last line before closing the function
 Application["pass_value"] = pass;
 Response.Redirect("~/webform2");
 Response.Redirect("two.aspx", true);->Not required

in webform2.aspx:
Label1.Text = Application["pass_value"].ToString();

in webform2.aspx.cs design page:
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```